# Can a function $f:[0,2\pi] \rightarrow 1$ have a PDF and CDF?

Tags: probability

Consider an interval $X = [0,2\pi]$ Assume $X$ has a uniform distribution. 
Let $f: X \rightarrow 1$ be a transformation of the $X$ to a random variable $Y$ whose only member is the number $1$

Can I define a CDF for $f(X)$?

---

I am having trouble answering this but I have some thoughts. I am a bit confused because it seems very weird to map all of $X$ onto a single number. Doesn't that effectively mean $\Bbb P(y = 1) = 1$ if $x\in [0,2\pi]$ but $\Bbb P(y=1) = 0 $ if $x\notin [0,2\pi]$? There aren't any other possible values for $y$ so it seems like this must be the answer. However, usually my CDF are all written such that $x$ is no longer relevant and everything is in terms of $y$, so I feel like this reasoning can't be right even though it makes sense.

Comment: How $X=[0,2\pi]$ (an interval) be a random variable? Could you improve your writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean is $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$ and $Y=f(X)$, where $f(x) \equiv 1$ for all $x$. (In particular, this means $X$ is a *random variable*, not an *interval*.)

The problem with this definition is that $Y$ is not a random variable, because its pdf is exactly $$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 1, & y \in [0,2\pi], \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}$$
which means
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} f_Y(y) \, dy = \int_0^{2\pi} 1 \, dy = 2\pi \ne 1 \cdots
$$

Can you finish this?

Comment: Ah, damn. I actually did that very calculation but erased it because I thought it was wrong. I assumed I made a mistake because I didn't know what it meant. By definition, probabilities must sum to one, and these don't. So what does that mean? Presumably if $X$ had been $[0,1]$, this would have worked. But it doesn't with $2\pi$ so I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @StanShunpike it means you cannot construct the CDF :), because $Y$ is not a valid random variable. You are right, if is was on any interval of length $1$, e.g. $[0,1]$ or possibly $[\pi, \pi+1]$, it would work just fine :).

Comment: What if the domain is only $[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: @StanShunpike not sure domain of what you are asking about. If domain of $f$ it wouldn't change much...